# Can i open UIImagePickerController with it's previous position were photo is selected?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

For example. I am presenting `UIImagePickerController` and store it's `strong reference`.
Now there is list of `A,B` and `C` album.
From album `B` i select one photo and dismiss `UIImagePickerController`.
Now while i re-open `UIImagePickerController` from `strong reference` for picking photo i am getting album list of `(A,B and C)` so is there any way to show directly album `B's` photos ?

Comment: As is common I feel the need to ask for some posting of code to see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to do this with an `UIImagePickerController`.  If you want something like that you need to create your own version.

Answer (score 0):

**UIImagePickerController** just open your photos from **Gallery**. You cannot make default selection for a photo. You can use [my library](https://github.com/NirmalsinhRathod/CreolePhotoSelection) for it.